# Multiple IF statements in Google Spread Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to nest multiple IF statements using Google spread sheet.

Here's my formula:

```
=IF(C7=1,"5",IF(E7=1,"2",IF(C7+E7=2,"7")))
```

C7 with a 1 outputs 5
E7 with a 1 outputs 2
C7 + E7 with a 1 outputs 5

I'm trying to make it so if C7 AND E7 have a 1 then it outputs 7.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
=if(and(isnumber(C7),isnumber(E7)),if(and(C7=1,E7=1),"7",if(C7+E7=1,"5",if(C7=1,"5",if(E7=1,"2","something else")))),"not a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
=if(and(isnumber(C7),isnumber(E7)),if(and(C7=1,E7=1),"7",if(C7+E7=1,"5",if(C7=1,"5",if(E7=1,"2","0")))),"NaN")
```

Explaining it:

The and function passes true if both the arguments are true.
In this case, if C7 contains a number and E7 contains a number then you satisfy the first IF. if it's a number it checks if they're ones. if they are then it displays 7. if not it checks if C7 + E7 = 1. If that's correct then it spits out a 5. if not then it checks again if only C7 is 1. if it's correct it spits out a 5. if not it checks if E7=1 if that's correct it spits out a 2 if not it spits out a 0. If C7 and E7 weren't numbers to begin with then it's gonna display "NaN" which means not a number